# Fetching data every time page is reloaded

Tags: reactjs, laravel, rest

I am creating an eCommerce-type website with react and Laravel with the REST APIs. Every time user enters page [www.mywebsite.com/products](http://www.mywebsite.com/products) a rest API is called to get all the products, and it takes like a second to load all of them. If the user leaves the page and enters it again, the same request is called, and the same products are loaded.

My question is: What's the best approach for this situation? Maybe I should somehow fetch the products only once, store them inside localStorage and get them using Context? On the other hand, most of the websites I visit seem to load products instantly, so maybe even the REST API is the wrong approach for this kind of website?

Comment: Can you fetch only products, required on current page? Say you have tens of thousands of different products - I don't think you want to show them all at once. Of course if you have 10-20 products, then it makes sense fetch them all - but loading so few products should not take seconds - maybe your rest api is sub-optimal then?

Comment: I would normally recommend something like react query for this sort of issue. Worth taking a look into it

Comment: My products also has reviews and categories(many-to-many relationship). Every-time i fetch products it returns all of it's reviews, categories, parent of category and children of category. I think that's why it's taking so long but i need all of this data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check your DB queries and investigate why this request takes so long. Have a look at the laravel Telescope package: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/telescope

In the request tab you can follow your requests and see which queries are the most expensive ones. My guess is that you're lazy loading some relations on each product.

Next I would propably cache the articles (expect maybe the stock information). Use the built-in feature of laravel or maybe a third party package like [this one](https://leqc.renoki.org)

Only then I would go for client-side optimizations. Here you should consider maybe a state management extension like [akita](https://datorama.github.io/akita/).